# How to change color of a 3D mesh in Kivy?

Tags: python, 3d, kivy

I wanted to use Kivy to render 3D meshes, which I could translate, rotate and change their colors. I managed to simplify/edit [Niko Skrypnik's Rubik's cube](https://github.com/nskrypnik/kivy-rubik) and now I have this code, which just renders a rotatable red square:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.resources import resource_find
from kivy.graphics.transformation import Matrix
from kivy.graphics import *

class Renderer(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        self.vertices = [[ -1,-1, 0,
                            1,-1, 0,
                            1, 1,-0,
                           -1, 1, 0]]

        kw['shader_file'] = 'shaders.glsl'
        self.canvas = RenderContext(compute_normal_mat=True)
        shader_file = kw.pop('shader_file')
        self.canvas.shader.source = resource_find(shader_file)

        with self.canvas:
            Translate(0, 0, -4.5)
            self.rot = Rotate(0, 1, 1, 1)
            ChangeState(Kd=(1.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                        Ka=(1.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                        Ks=(.3, .3, .3),
                        Tr=1.,
                        Ns=1.,
                        intensity=1.)
            for i in xrange(len(self.vertices)):
                Mesh(   vertices=self.vertices[i],
                        indices=[0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 2],
                        fmt=[('v_pos', 3, 'float')],
                        mode='triangles')

        asp = float(Window.width) / Window.height / 2.0
        proj = Matrix().view_clip(-asp, asp, -0.5, 0.5, 1, 100, 1)
        self.canvas['projection_mat'] = proj

        Window.request_keyboard(None, self).bind(on_key_down = self.on_keyboard_down)

    def on_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        if keycode[1] == "left": self.rot.angle -= 10
        elif keycode[1] == "right": self.rot.angle += 10

class MyApp(App):
     def build(self):
         return Renderer()

if __name__ == '__main__':
     MyApp().run()
```

Note: I used `shaders.glsl` from the Rubik's cube project on Github.
Using the same principle I can translate or scale it, but I have not figured out how to change its color. The only way that worked, was basically clean the canvas and render it again, but I believe that there is a better way.
Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass uniform variables to the shaders through the RenderContext `__setitem__`. In this case, the colours (both inherent and lighting) are through the Kd and Ka variables, so you could do something like:

```
self.canvas['Kd'] = [0., 1., 0.]
self.canvas['Ka'] = [0., 1., 0.]
```

This should make everything green.

You could (of course) do something similar for any other uniform variable in the shaders.

Comment: May I have an additional question? Using this I can have only one color per canvas, can't I? Of course I could use more canvases, but that would cause a problem for example with perspective (a further object could be dependently on time of addition rendered in front of a closer object).

Comment: These variables are uniform variables, which can only have one value at a time in a shader. It sounds like you want to pass and use vertex attributes, which may be different for each vertex.

Comment: Yes, but how do I access/use those vertex attributes?